# Changing Button Background Programmatically not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background

I have a Stack Panel, that contains three buttons. When a button is clicked I want the background to stay permanently changed, however it doesn't seem to working.

I've tried to set the background colour programmatically as I've written below however it doesn't seem to work. When I set the foreground colour programmatically that works, changing the colours as instructed. I think as I'm using a template for the buttons in the XAML, where I assign a background colour, has priority over a programmatic change.

Attempt at changing background:

```
AColour.Background = Brushes.Black;
BColour.Background = Brushes.Red;
CColour.Background = Brushes.Black;
```

Attempt to change foreground (which works):

```
AColour.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
BColour.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
CColour.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

XAML (Button Template):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border Name="body" Background="#AEEEEE" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="DimGray" Padding="2">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="body" Value="#12CCD3"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="body" Value="#009DA2"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

XAML Button Declaration (Same for all 3 buttons except name):

```
 <Button Cursor="Hand" x:Name="AColour" Height="40" Template="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Width ="100" Click="A_Click">
```

Is there any way (if the template is having priority) to overwrite the template and change the background programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have set button's background to "#AEEEEE" explicit, so ,the button's background will not changed by code.

I think you should use TemplateBinding in you Template,like this:

```
<Border  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter ...... />
    </Border>
```

Comment: So I was right about the template having priority over programmatic declarations of button controls. Your suggestion was perfect though and resolved the issue, thankyou!